# To extract the threshold values of the alarms using python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, cloudwatch

```
   alarms = c.describe_alarms()
   for alarm in alarms:
       print alarm.name
       print alarm.metric
       print alarm.namespace
```

I have got all the alarms associated with the RDS. Now i need to find the threshold values for these alarms. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: using boto2 or boto3?

Comment: Forget about boto, just go straigh to boto3.
 
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.describe_alarms

Comment: Thanks :) @pjz It worked..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it can be retrieved with `boto`. You might have to use `boto3`, which shows the full datastructure in the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.describe_alarms).

If you *must* use `boto`, you might try grabbing one alarm and doing `print repr(alarm)` and seeing if the threshold is in the output somewhere.

Comment: Thankyou!! :) i will up vote you once i'm eligible to do so :)